# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement streamlit==1.19.0

Tags: pip, anaconda, streamlit

While running

```
pip install streamlit==1.19.0
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement streamlit==1.19.0 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.11.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.4, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.3, 0.13.5, 0.14.2, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.15.3, 0.15.4, 0.15.5, 0.15.6, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.16.3, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.20.0, 0.21.0, 0.22.0, 0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.23.0, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.24.3, 0.25.0, 0.26.0, 0.26.1, 0.27.0, 0.28.0, 0.29.0, 0.30.0, 0.31.0, 0.32.0, 0.33.0, 0.34.0, 0.35.0, 0.36.0, 0.37.0, 0.40.0, 0.40.1, 0.41.0, 0.42.0, 0.43.0, 0.43.1, 0.43.2, 0.44.0, 0.45.0, 0.46.0, 0.47.0, 0.47.1, 0.47.2, 0.47.3, 0.47.4, 0.48.0, 0.48.1, 0.49.0, 0.50.0, 0.50.1, 0.50.2, 0.51.0, 0.52.0, 0.52.1, 0.52.2, 0.53.0, 0.54.0, 0.55.0, 0.56.0, 0.57.0, 0.57.1, 0.57.2, 0.57.3, 0.58.0, 0.59.0, 0.60.0, 0.61.0, 0.62.0, 0.62.1, 0.63.0, 0.63.1, 0.64.0, 0.65.0, 0.65.1, 0.65.2, 0.66.0, 0.67.0, 0.67.1, 0.68.0, 0.68.1, 0.69.0, 0.69.1, 0.69.2, 0.70.0, 0.71.0, 0.72.0, 0.73.0, 0.73.1, 0.74.0, 0.74.1, 0.75.0, 0.76.0, 0.77.0, 0.78.0, 0.79.0, 0.80.0, 0.81.0, 0.81.1, 0.82.0, 0.83.0, 0.84.0, 0.84.1, 0.84.2, 0.85.0, 0.85.1, 0.86.0, 0.87.0, 0.88.0, 0.89.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc3, 1.6.0rc4, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1rc1, 1.8.1, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1rc1, 1.9.1rc2, 1.9.1, 1.9.2rc1, 1.9.2, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0rc2, 1.10.0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for streamlit==1.19.0
```

I tried mirror sites though I am in the North America, but failed. I tried to update pip 21.2.3 to pip 23.0.1, tried `conda update conda`, but none of them worked. I also went to Anaconda navigator's "environment" and found the latest streamlit is 1.16.0 (which is conflicted with above error message--1.12.0). I also tried to update anaconda navigator, still didn't work. Also what's strange is that after yesterday's these updating, I go to "environment" today and streamlit module disappears. While the error message above persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Streamlit 1.2.1, Python 3.9.7 was excluded from the supported versions. See the [Streamlit associated Pull Request](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/pull/5168).

Also, on Pypi:

[image: Pypi image of python requirements. Streamlit requires Python >= 3.7, !=3.9.7]

Therefore, the latest Python version available for this version of Python is 1.2.0.

To solve this, you need to upgrade (or downgrade) your Python version to any version satisfying ">= 3.7, !=3.9.7".

Comment: Not sure this is accurate. From snowflakes' website it clearly say treamlit support all python versions from 3.8,3.9,3.10 etc. : https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/deploy-your-app#

Comment: Well.. the package metadata say otherwise. See https://pypi.org/project/streamlit/1.30.0/

Answer (score 0):

I installed streamlit version 1.27.1 successfully with python version 3.10.0 after struggling with this error for some time:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement streamlit (from versions: none)

The problem could be a connection issue. Or firewall on your user windows account. Streamit installed as soon as I disconnected from the company work WIFI and connected to my personal router.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).